# How to access a variable inside request.get function in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to access a local variable in callback request.get..

```
var GetData = function(req, res){
     var code = req.query.code;
     request.get({url: 'www.example.com?code='+ code}, function(err, res){
          if(err){
              console.log(err)
          }else{
              console.log(result);
          }
     })
}
```

How can i use code variable inside request.get( ) function?
Thank you..

Comment: Have you tested this code, you haven't declared result anywhere, you must be getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm ... you can access to the variable, because the `code` variable (in `get()` scope) will refer to the `GetData` scope.

**EDIT :** Here's a JSFiddle to prove it : https://jsfiddle.net/zawbdxah/1/